# Is it possible to get an xpath element using javascript, without using document.evaluate()?

Tags: javascript, document.evaluate

The reason I wish to do this is because document.evaluate() does not work in IE. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Have you tried [js-xpath](http://js-xpath.sourceforge.net/), which provides `document.evaluate` support for IE?

Comment: Although I can't answer the question, I can help you get better answers faster with a question naming hint: instead of mentioning what you *don't* want to use, mention what you *do* want (for example *Can I/How do I use XPath in Javascript with IE?*)